# Spinner selection modifies listView

Tags: android, listview, android-spinner

How can I can change my ListView when I select a value from Spinner menu?  I have a spinner with two options: order by date, order by name. When I select order by date, the ListView which contains elements in a random order, must show elements ordered by name.

I have the ListView elements(ordered by name and date) stored in two String arrays, so the only thing I have to do is when the user clicks the spinner, check which of the two options was selected, and update the ListView with one of the Strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the appropriate array to pick in the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged on the list view